# Python3-pip installation error | The following packages have unmet dependencies:

Tags: pip, python-3.6

```
apt install python3-pip

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Breaks: libgcc-9-dev (< 9.3.0-5~) but 9.2.1-19 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: instead of using apt try the other methods

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

or
download get-pip.py from here:
https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

then run :

```
python get-pip.py
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can`t starting script of Divyessh, try to install python3 and start command:

```
python3 get-pip.py
```